# Does anybody make and sell stickers with the ROS logo and related products/brands/companies?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can I get stickers for ROS, related products, and the companies that produce them?

I suddenly have a great desire to put stickers on my laptop after living in Silicon Valley for sometime now. I also want to stick them on my robots and STOP signs. Does anybody make and sell stickers with the ROS logo and related products/brands/companies? I would love to have stickers for the things like OpenCV, Turtlebot, OSRF, Gazebo, Willow Garage, Yujin, Kobuki, OpenNI, Clearpath, etc.

Bonus points for scratch N' sniff

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65629/does-anybody-make-and-sell-stickers-with-the-ros-logo-and-related-products/brands/companies?/) by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1209 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are [stickers available on Zazzle](https://www.zazzle.com/store/openrobotics/products?dp=0&cg=196936312033387169&rf=238583394320947238) As well as [Posters](https://www.zazzle.com/store/openrobotics/products?dp=0&cg=196892405499231339&rf=238583394320947238) and [Canvas Prints](https://www.zazzle.com/store/openrobotics/products?dp=0&cg=196964974640243022&rf=238583394320947238)

[General maketing materials are listed here.](http://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Marketing.html?highlight=stickers)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: Unfortunately the Fieldhouse Store has closed.

There's a build-to-order [online store](http://fieldhouse.com/osrf) linked from `OSRF`'s web site. Unfortunately I don't find stickers, but they have [kids stuff](http://fhstore.com/Shopping/FHShop2.aspx?PON=74635&CON=75767&CNUM=0&RNUM=0&SCN=77&CN=179&ASN=&AC=) and all kinds of apparels, where you can choose logos from `OSRF`, `Gazebo`, `ROS` and `Turtlebot` afaik.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2017-02-12**:
Now, the store doesn't have anything... I'd love to have a ROS sticker

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-02-12**:
@andrestoga I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't have anything". I just visited the [same website](http://fieldhouse.com/osrf) linked above and I see custom products.

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2017-02-12**:
My mistake. You're right. I just opened the website and saw it empty and I thought there was nothing.